# How parse the log file use python , and output html?

Tags: python, regex

Here is one line of log file :

```
41.42.50.xxx - - [09/Oct/2012:00:00:01 +0200] "GET http://www.xxxxxx.com/solutions-ar/solutions-1466.php HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "http://www.google.com.eg/url?dfasdfeaefdf" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
```

i want to parse the ip address, time, url, google url and browser to single line,
i use `(r'^(((2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?))')` to match the ip address, how can i get the other info and output html ?
Thanks

Comment: That regex is really overly paranoid...`^(?:\d+\.){3}\d+` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, i'll improve it, but how can i parse the other info rest of the line ?

Comment: Do you have any other examples of log lines?  Would help with things like date, etc.--will the month always be three letters?  Will anything else ever be inside `[]`?

Comment: how do you want it in html - as a table or smth else?

Comment: @jdotjdot89 : yes, everyline's structure is the same, the time ever be inside []

Comment: @root table is fine，how can i iterate it in table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- IP Address: `r'^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'`
- Time: `r'\d{2}/[a-zA-Z]{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4}'`
- Time (*alternate*): `r'(?<=\[).+?(?=\])'`, lazy, assuming date will always be inside `[]` and only date will ever be inside `[]`
- URL: `r'https?://.+?(?= HTTP)'`
- Google URL: `r'(?<=")https?://.*?google\..*?(?=")'`
- Browser: `r'(?<=")Mozilla.+?(?=")'`

However, as **nneonneo** pointed out, using a tool like apachelog will be a lot more robust and reliable.

Comment: Thank you very much~ by the way, i parse the url from resources without google, and like bing, yahoo search engin and so on, i want to parse the keyword behind ?q= or q=, how can i match the keyword ? i use (?<=q=)|(?<?q=), i don't think it's right, : (, can you help me with fix it ? thankyou!

Comment: For a new question, it's best if you open up a new Stack Overflow question.  I'd be happy to answer it there.  Feel free to message me the link when you've done so so I can answer it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831537/parse-and-match-the-keyword-in-search-engine-url-use-python-re   Thank you again : )

Answer (score 3):

Use a library like [apachelog](http://code.google.com/p/apachelog/) to parse the Apache log lines. It will be more robust and safer than trying to write a regex for the lines.