# How do you parse and match the keyword in search engine url using python re module?

Tags: python, regex, asciiencoding

Example from Google:

```
http://www.google.com.co/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pedro%20gomez%20proyecto%20en%20la%20ciudad%20de%20valledupar&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CFsQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.21molino.com%2F1410%2F8911.html
```

or from Bing search:

```
http://www.bing.com/search?q=10%2F30+Sand&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC
```

I want parse and match `?q=` or `q=` keywords, using `(?<=)?` with the python `re` module.
How can you can pass the multiple parameters in encode the ascii url to utf-8 so that it can be read?

Need some help here, thanks very much : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[?&]q=([^&#]*)
```

Or, better yet:

```
import urlparse
pr = urlparse.urlparse(url)
qs = urlparse.parse_qs(pr.query)['q']
```

The latter automatically decodes `%`-escapes, too.

Comment: Thank you nneonneo : ) if q=%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%84+%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA+%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AF+%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1 like this after utf-8 quote, how can i uncode it and get the keywords?

Comment: Use `urlparse`, as I said. It will be a less painful way to decode the URL.

Comment: By the way, if parse the yandex results, it include ?p= or text=

Comment: if use urlparse, can pass muiltiple params ?

Comment: `urlparse` handles the whole URL.

Comment: Cuz the doc is English, difficult for me : ) not my first Lang, i'll check it, thank you